# Loop through an array of dates and find sets of two days in a row and merge values

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
$cakedays = array ( 
     2019-06-27 = "Dave"
     2019-07-09 = "Rob, James, Brian"
     2019-07-16 = "Sam"
     2019-07-17 = "Kate"
     2019-07-23 = "Alex"
     2019-07-24 = "Jen"
     2019-07-25 = "Pete, Tong"
     )
```

I want to loop through this array and if I find two days in a row I want to merge the two names on the second day. But only for each set of two days in a row, not three or more days.

So the resulting array looks like this

```
 $cakedays = array ( 
     2019-06-27 = "Dave"
     2019-07-09 = "Rob, James, Brian"
     2019-07-17 = "Sam, Kate"
     2019-07-24 = "Alex, Jen"
     2019-07-25 = "Pete, Tong"
     )
```

This is the logic I have so far but it breaks down when I hit three days in a row. Its late and logic to sort it escapes me right now.

```
 $days = [];
    $arr2 = [];
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($cakedays as $date => $values){
        $days[] = $date;
        $arr2[$date] = $values;

        if($i !== 0){
            $date1 = new DateTime($days[$i]);
            $date2 = new DateTime($days[$i - 1]);

            $diff = $date1->diff($date2);
            $names = [];
            if ($diff->days === 1) {
                $names[] = $arr2[$date2->format('Y-m-d')];
                $names[] = $arr2[$date1->format('Y-m-d')];

                unset($arr2[$date2->format('Y-m-d')]);
                $arr2[$date] = implode(", ", $names);
            }
        }
        $i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array =
[
    '2019-06-27' => 'Dave',
    '2019-07-09' => 'Rob, James, Brian',
    '2019-07-16' => 'Sam',
    '2019-07-17' => 'Kate',
    '2019-07-23' => 'Alex',
    '2019-07-24' => 'Jen',
    '2019-07-25' => 'Pete, Tong'
];

$ignore = [];

foreach ($array as $today => $names)
{
    if (isset($ignore[$today]))
    {
        continue;
    }


    $tomorrow = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$today +1 day"));

    if (!isset($array[$tomorrow]))
    {
        continue;
    }


    $array[$tomorrow] = "$names, $array[$tomorrow]";

    $ignore[$tomorrow] = true;

    unset($array[$today]);
}
```